# tsql return identity values when inserting multiple records into a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, identity

I have a situation where I need to insert multiple records/batch insert into a view which has instead of trigger. How can I retrieve the inserted identity values? I tried using the OUTPUT clause to retrieve the Id from the Inserted table but it always returns null.

Comment: You can use the `OUTPUT` clause inside the `INSTEAD OF` trigger itself. Perhaps with conditional logic checking `CONTEXT_INFO` to know whether to call an insert statement with or without the clause.#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this setup.

```
create table InsteadOf
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(10) not null
)

go

create view v_InsteadOf
as
select ID, Name
from InsteadOf

go

create trigger tr_InsteadOf on InsteadOf instead of insert
as
begin
  insert into InsteadOf(Name)
  select Name
  from inserted
end
```

The statement

```
insert into v_InsteadOf(Name)
output inserted.*
select 'Name1' union all 
select 'Name2'
```

Will give you an error.

> Msg 334, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The target table 'InsteadOf' of the
>   DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement
>   contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

Using an INTO clause with the insert instead.

```
declare @IDs table(ID int, Name varchar(10))

insert into v_InsteadOf(Name)
output inserted.* into @IDs
select 'Name1' union all 
select 'Name2'

select *
from @IDs
```

Gives you `0` as a value not `null`.

```
ID          Name
----------- ----------
0           Name1
0           Name2
```

You can put the output clause in the trigger.

```
create trigger tr_InsteadOf on InsteadOf instead of insert
as
begin
  insert into InsteadOf(Name)
  output inserted.*
  select Name
  from inserted
end
```

And the output will be generated for you when you do the insert.

```
insert into v_InsteadOf(Name)
select 'Name1' union all 
select 'Name2'
```

Result:

```
ID          Name
----------- ----------
1           Name1
2           Name2
```

**Update:**
To capture the output from the insert statement you can use `insert into ... exec (...)`

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(10)
)

insert into @T
exec
  (
    'insert into v_InsteadOf(Name)
     values (''Name1''),(''Name2'')'
  )
```

Comment: How can I store these returned values to table variable for later use? The below query returns 0 as id for the rows inserted.

DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, NAME Varchar(10))
INSERT INTO v_InsteadOf(Name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @T
VALUES ('gk'),('gv')

SELECT * FROM @T